# dwg to sqlitedb or mbtiles to use it as map in galillo for mobile

Tags: georeferencing

how can convert dwg to sqlitedb or mbtiles to use it as map in galillo for mobile or any other extension that can work in gps program for mobile
dwg contain map i n stereografic reference and how can georeference to wgs84 and view it in correct place